# Fill an array/list with hourly differential values - given two time values from drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I am trying to fill an array/list with values from a time subtraction. I have start time in this format "09.00 AM" and End time in the same format ex: "06.00 PM", both times are coming from two drop downs (values from 9 am to 9 pm with hourly increments) which are actually jquery time picker controls. This is what I am trying to do.. after user selects both times, I want to populate an array/list with individual "hour" mark values that fall between the two selected time values. For ex: selecting 9 am and 12 pm should give me values { "10.00 AM", "11.00 AM"}.. selecting 10 AM to 4 PM should give me {"11.00 AM", "12.00 PM", "01.00 PM", "02.00 PM", "03.00 PM"}..

```
var FirstTime = container.find('#1time').val();
var SecondTime = container.find('#2time').val(); 

var busyTimes = [];
busyTimes =  getBusyTimes(FirstTime , SecondTime);
```

Function js:

```
function getBusyTimes(first, second) {
    var f = first.split(' '), s = second.split(' ');
    if (first == '12.00 AM') f[0] = '0';
    if (first == '12.00 PM') f[1] = 'AM';
    if (second == '12.00 AM') s[0] = '24';
    if (second == '12.00 PM') s[1] = 'AM';
    f[0] = parseInt(f[0], 10) + (f[1] == 'PM' ? 12 : 0);
    s[0] = parseInt(s[0], 10) + (s[1] == 'PM' ? 12 : 0);
    int i = s[0] - f[0];
    // I have difference in hours in "i"
    //From here, I want to make use of value 'i' -- calculate in between   
    // hourly values and return the array back to 
    // original function above.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this but it should work for what you are trying to do and it should operate faster than the calculations you are trying to do.

```
function getBusyTimes(first, second){
var timeList = ['12:00 AM','1:00 AM','2:00 AM','3:00 AM']; // finish this list
var firstid  = timeList.indexOf(first);
var secondid = timeList.indexOf(second);
var result = new Array();
for(var i=firstid; i<=secondid; i++ ){
    result.push(timeList[i]);
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: That works! http://jsfiddle.net/H8Nd5/1/ - i've made a modification to allow second time to be earlier ie. from 11 PM to 6 AM